Is there any way to get complex object from query string in ASP.NET Core 8?
I'm trying to get a complex object from query string, object has some primitive types and 2 arrays of classes for filtering and sorting, but when I get the object from query string these 2 arrays are empty.
I was trying to ask Chat-GPT about it, googled this problem and have not found anything that can help me.
This is my DTO:
public record GetItemsSortedDto(
    int ParentId,
    SortingFieldDto[]? SortFields,
    Filter[]? Filters,
    int Page = 1,
    int PageSize = 10,
    string OrderColumn = "Number",
    bool IsSortedAsc = true)
    : IStandardForTypesOfConstructionDto;

public class SortingFieldDto
{
    public string Field { get; set; } = "Number";
    public object RangeStart { get; set; } = null!;
    public object RangeEnd { get; set; } = null!;
}

public class Filter
{
    public string Id { get; set; } = "TypeOfConstruction";
    [FromQuery(Name = "Value")]
    public string[] Values { get; set; } = null!;
}

And here is my controller method
[HttpGet("ItemsSorted")]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetItemsSorted([FromQuery] GetItemsSortedDto getDto)
{
      var query = _mapper.Map<GetItemsByParentSortedQuery>(getDto);

      var result = await Mediator.Send(query);
      return Ok(query);
}  

I was trying to use model binding, but there was no success. In the DTO, I need to store arrays of sorting and filtering, so I can sort and filter more than 1 column simultaneously.

There's nothing stopping you from accepting values as a string and then parsing out individual items from that string if needed. It's slightly clunkier than relying on model binding, but still perfectly doable. Alternatively - don't post this data in query string. Post it as part of the body of the request (with JSON).

Update:
Above solution should help for binding objects with [fromBody] attribute, but unfortunately (same documentation):
"Route data and query string values are used only for simple types."
So you cannot bind a complex object from just the query string.
Original:
From the Microsoft Documentation for Model Binding (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-8.0#complex-types)
"A complex type must have a public default constructor and public writable properties to bind".
Your Dto class uses the new constructor model (which shouldn't be a problem), but it only has fields and no properties.
I would try refactoring the fields to actual properties.

I've added this
public class GetItemsSortedDto : IStandartForTypesOfConstructionDto
{
public int ParentId { get; set; }
public SortingFieldDto[]? SortFields { get; set; }
[BindRequired] public Filter[]? Filters { get; set; }
public int Page { get; set; } = 1;
public int PageSize { get; set; } = 10;
public string OrderColumn { get; set; } = "Number";
public bool IsSortedAsc { get; set; } = true;
}
instead of record and nothing changed. Did you mean to do this or no?

Yes, but I just found something else in the documentation:
"Route data and query string values are used only for simple types."
So what you are trying to do is not possible, unfortunately.

Okay, but thank you for the help
